# Problems creating a chart/histogram in C#

Tags: c#, charts, histogram

I am trying to learn C#, and as an exercise for myself, I have coded the Box-Muller method, and am now trying to plot a histogram of my simulated datapoints to check if the data looks fairly normal.

For creating the histogram, I am following this guide here: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/uiux/2756-getting-started-with-net-charts.html

I have included my code so far below. My problem is that I get squiggly red lines under "chart1" in the main method, and I get the error "The name 'chart1' does not exist in the current context'. There seem to be nothing from the guide that I am missing. Can anyone clear up what I am missing?

Best regards.

```js
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            double[] normalData = new double[200];
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Tuple<double, double> Z = BoxMuller(i);
                normalData[2 * i - 2] = Z.Item1;
                normalData[2 * i - 1] = Z.Item2;
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", normalData[2 * i - 2], normalData[2 * i - 1]);
            }

            //Trying to make a simple histogram (to begin with)
            DataPoint Dp = new DataPoint();
            Dp.SetValueY(3);
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart1.Series.Add("My Data");
        }


        static Tuple<double, double> BoxMuller(int i)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(i);
            double U1 = rand.NextDouble();
            double U2 = rand.NextDouble();
            double R = -2 * Math.Log(U1);
            double V = 2 * Math.PI * U2;

            double Z1 = Math.Sqrt(R) * Math.Cos(V);
            double Z2 = Math.Sqrt(R) * Math.Sin(V);

            Tuple<double, double> tuple = new Tuple<double, double>(Z1, Z2);
            return tuple;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've missed this part from the guide: "Using the Chart control is very easy. Just select it from the toolbox, you will find it grouped with the other Data controls and drop it on a form.". This also won't be possible with a Console application which is what you've created. You need a Windows Forms application.

Comment: Looks like you are creating a Command line application. These __can__ create and use Charts, but only to save them, __not to show them__.. You probably want to restart with a WinForms application

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I can get the histograms to work when starting with a WinForm application :) - but the concept seems weird to me: I have a window called "Form1" on which I dragged a "chart" from the Toolbox. Is this drag-and-drop concept only meant as an aid to the programmer, that is, can I write a program from scratch that gives me the exact same output without using the Toolbox? Or is it necessary to do it in this way to get a histogram? @Karl-JohanSjögren

Comment: Also, I am confused about the "Console application" vs. "WinForm application" thing. Isn't it possible for me to start a new project as a blank slate, without specifying what kind of application it is? And then the code determinates exactly the behavior and output of the program.

Comment: When you start your project you mostly select a project type (winform/console/library etc). This is mostly to help the IDE setup the proper templates and determines how the compiler is executed. If you work outside of Visual Studio you can skip this entirely and just call the compiler yourself but Visual Studio needs to know what type the project is if it shall be able to help you. You can create winform applications without the drag and drop as well, but it isn't a very pleasant experience.